# EntityObject.Remove() does not delete record from database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am relatively new to Entity Framework 4.

My project consists of a WebApplication & ClassLibrary project. I had to use ADO.Net POCO entity generator since I have multiple edmx files with certain common models in between in the ClassLibrary project.

Within an edmx I have tables for User, Role & UserRole (containing only 2 foreign keys columns, UserID & RoleID). Entity Framework has created two models namely User and Role with navigation properties of Roles and Users respectively. I have removed the definingQuery from the .edmx, which enables me to add records into the UserRole table.

In my webform I have this code:
To insert a role:

```
User user = new User(iUserID);  //initializes the the user object with the user info 
user.AddRole(RoleID);           //passes in the roleid that needs to be inserted`
```

To delete a user's role:

```
User user = new User(iUserID);  //initializes the the user object with the user info
user.RemoveRole(RoleID);        //passes in the roleid that needs to be deleted`
```

Content of Partial User class (Constructor & 2 methods):

```
public User(short UserID)
{
    using (SecurityEntities Context = new SecurityEntities())
    {
        User user = Context.Users.Where(ua => ua.UserID == UserID).Single<User>();
        this.UserID = user.UserID;
        // etc...
    }
}

public void AddRole(short roleID)
{
    using (SecurityEntities Context = new SecurityEntities())
    {
        Role role = Context.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleID == roleID).Single<Role>();
        Context.AttachTo("Users", this);
        this.Roles.Add(role);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public void RemoveRole(short roleID)
{
    using (SecurityEntities Context = new SecurityEntities())
    {
        Role role = Context.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleID == roleID).Single<Role>();
        Context.AttachTo("Users", this);
        this.Roles.Remove(role);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My questions are

1. In the AddRole method, if I don't use AttachTo() a duplicate record of the current user is entered into the User table and the role is inserted into UserRole against it. Why does attachTo() prevent this from happening?
2. In the RemoveRole method, the code runs smoothly without error but the record in the table does not get deleted. Why?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are using entity framework incorrectly in both cases. The user is created by (then tracked) a different context. Then you retrieve the role using different context instance.

Either supply the context instance which created the `user` to the method

```
public void AddRole(SecurityEntities Context, short roleID)
{
        Role role = Context.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleID == roleID).Single<Role>();

        this.Roles.Add(role);
        Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

or supply the `Role` instance to the method

```
public void AddRole(Role role)
{
        this.Roles.Add(role);
}
```

Remove method also suffer similar issue

```
public void RemoveRole(short roleID)
{
     var role = this.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleID == roleID).Single();
     this.Roles.Remove(role);
}
```

Important thing is to use the entities that belong to single context instance. Otherwise you will have to detach from previous context and attach to the current context.

Comment: Dear Eranga, I cannot pass the context object to the web page function from where the initial call created the user object. However as you have suggested I have supplied Role object to the removeRole method and tried all sort of things (detaching /attaching etc) 
but the records simply do not get deleted. 
Can you please explain how do I detach and attach the Role object as suggested.

Comment: @RaviShet In the last 2 examples the `SaveChanges` method should be called by the caller of the `RemoveRole` method